# Что не так с кодом?

Tags: javascript

Есть следующий HTML:

```
<div id="hide">
    <button id="click">Клик</button>
</div>
<div id="acitve" style="display:none;"></div>
```

и вот такой скрипт:

```
var hide = document.querySelector('#hide');
var click = document.querySelector('#click');
var active = document.querySelector('#active');
click.onClick = function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        hide.style.display = 'none';
        acitve.style.display = 'block';
    },2000);
}
```

Почему он не срабатывает, даже ошибок нету.

Comment: `onclick` вместо `onClick`

Comment: да)) регистр... но блин... чет он не так работает) скрипт должен по нажатию на кнопку на 2 секунды ее убирать и отображать блок с id "active". а он жмет на кнопку и через 2секунды выполняет код

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var hide = document.querySelector('#hide');
var click = document.querySelector('#click');
var active = document.querySelector('#active');
click.onclick = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    hide.style.display = 'none';
    acitve.style.display = 'block';
  }, 2000);
}
```

```html
<div id="hide"><button id="click">Клик</button></div>

И есть еще один:
<div id="acitve" style="display:none;">Active</div>
```